# Uninstalling a module

Tags: installation

In order to un-install a module I disabled and deleted the folder from the root module folder. Though I have deleted the module yet it's showing in *module list* page. Why is this? Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please follow link for details: https://www.drupal.org/node/250783

Answer (score 2):

Simply find the module name, and write the following command in your command-line/terminal/console to disable the module at first (by considering that the current path in your command-line is the Drupal project root directory):

```
drush dis moduleName -y
```

then after the completion of the executing the above command, write the following command to uninstall the module:

```
drush pm-uninstall moduleName -y
```

If you have several modules, you can list their names. For example for three modules, you can write:

```
drush dis moduleName1 moduleName2 moduleName3 -y 
drush pm-uninstall moduleName1 moduleName2 moduleName3 -y
```

Answer (score 1):

For uninstalling a module..

1. Disable the module in **Modules Page**.
2. Then **uninstall** module from **Uninstall Page**.
3. Then delete the module files if you want.

Comment: after disabling its not showing under uninstall page

Comment: **Not all modules have specific uninstall functions programmed in. A module will only show up on the uninstall tab if it has this feature. If it doesn't, skip this step and simply delete its files.**  from https://www.drupal.org/node/250783

Comment: did u flush cache...??

Comment: i could see one wonder, though i have deleted the module folder from root, if i go and check in admin->modules the module still exist, how could be possible?

Comment: check after flushing cache..

Comment: @kashish what module you are uninstalling? Either is it core or contributed?

Comment: @Abin: i flushed and checked

Comment: @WaQaRAli  I am using using custom module

Comment: **Core:** For core modules see *module* folder located at root.
**Contributed:** For contributed modules see *modules* folder located at `sites/all/modules`

Comment: module is developed by one of our developer

Comment: Where did you keep your module? show the exact path? also check your recent log messages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30301/discussion-between-kashish-and-waqar-ali).

Answer (score 1):

This may happen delete/remove the module before disabling in admin side....

Once again add and enable the same module...
and Click checked-box to disable and click save configuration button...
Now click uninstall link showed in top of the page and delete installed table...

Go to database system table...search module presence , if it is there delete rows and ensure....

Clear cache.... and ensure that cache table is empty....

Now **run cron**.php